# Verificar si tiene clave foranea y si no eliminar. Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Tengo mi tabla `proveedor` con un campo llamado `status` 1 activo 0 eliminado, solo hago un update al momento de eliminar

eliminar:

```
$data => array('status' => 0);
$this->db->update('proveedor',$data);
```

intente cambiar el update por `delete`

```
$this->db->delete('proveedor',$id);
```

el problema es que cuando hay datos relacionados con ese proveedor me marca error. Habra alguna forma de saber si ese proveedor esta relacionado con otra tabla, y si es así simplemente cambiar `status` de lo contrario poder utilizar `delete` y así evitar que haya registros innecesarios.

Las restricciones que tengo en mi BDD es

```
ON DELETE restrict, ON UPDATE cascade
```

Comment: Podrias declarar tu tabla en la base de datos con ON DELETE CASCADE.

Comment: lo tengo restrict, cascade no me iria bien

Answer (score 0):

`RESTRICT:` Es el comportamiento por defecto, que impide realizar modificaciones que atentan contra la integridad referencial.

Un registro se puede borrar cuando no existe registro relacionado en la tabla con la que se esta relacionando, en esta caso al usar `DELETE` estas violando esa restricción por lo tanto no lo va a eliminar.

Un `RESTRICT` en `MySQL` es básicamente lo mismo que un `NO ACTION`, prueba utilizando `SET NULL` ya que con esto lo que ara es establecer a `NULL` el valor de la clave secundaria cuando se elimina el registro en la tabla principal o se modifica el valor del campo referenciado.

Cabe mencionar que con esto quedaran datos en el aire, es decir, eliminaras los datos de tu tabla principal, pero los de las tablas referenciadas seguirán existiendo con el valor `NULL` y básicamente quedan en el aire.